# OnDataChange is never called of FIrebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database and need to create unique child node in database to start One to One chat. i am calling `FireBaseDatabase.updateChildren(RoomName)` to set single room for 2 user.

I am having issue in calling `FireBaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()`

and under this Listener none of the method calls not even on `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)`

Here is my code

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Hello I am SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "User Session Value " + userSession);
        userSession = new UserSession(getActivity(), "Pref_FileName");
        Log.d(TAG, "User Session Value After Init " + userSession);
        final Map<String, Object> RoomName = new HashMap<>();
        RoomTitle = userSession.getPhoneNO() + "-" + UserData.getPhone();
        otherUserRoom = UserData.getPhone() + "-" + userSession.getPhoneNO();
        Log.d(TAG, "Room Title Should Be " + RoomTitle);


        DatabaseReference FireBaseDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        Log.d(TAG, "Chat room name from Database " + db.toString());  //GETTING THIS VALUE IN LOG 

        FireBaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(RoomTitle)) {
                    intent2.putExtra("Get_Other",RoomTitle);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Room Exists No Need To Create It "+RoomTitle); // THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE
                    RoomNameFinal=RoomTitle;

                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(otherUserRoom)){
                    intent2.putExtra("Get_Other",otherUserRoom);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Room Exists No Need To Create It "+otherUserRoom);// THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE
                    RoomNameFinal=otherUserRoom;


                }

                else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"None Of the above Room exist so Create one with RoomTitle "+RoomName);// THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE
                    intent2.putExtra("Get_Other",RoomTitle);
                    RoomName.put(RoomTitle, "");
                    FireBaseDatabase.updateChildren(RoomName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.getDetails());  // THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.getMessage());  // THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.toString());    // THIS LOG NEVER GENERATE

            }


        });



        intent2.putExtra("Get_Phone", UserData.getPhone());
        intent2.putExtra("Get_Image", UserData.getImage());
        intent2.putExtra("Get_Name", UserData.getName());
        Log.d(TAG,"Room Name Final "+RoomNameFinal);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }
});
```

Edit:Where i am adding child in my Firebase Database
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by make some edit in code.I am not sure why this is happened but for some who still stuck at this issue, will get little help from this. Instead of calling `FireBaseDatabase.updateChildren(RoomName)` from directly in `onDataChange` i create a method which will be called from `onDataChange`

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Hello I am SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "User Session Value " + userSession);
        userSession = new UserSession(getActivity(), "Pref_File");

        RoomName = new HashMap<>();
        RoomTitle = userSession.getPhoneNO() + "-" + UserData.getPhone();
        otherUserRoom = UserData.getPhone() + "-" + userSession.getPhoneNO();
        Log.d(TAG, "Room Title Should Be " + RoomTitle);


        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        Log.d(TAG, "Chat room name from Database " + db.toString());


        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override

            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG,"On Data Change Calling "+dataSnapshot);
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(RoomTitle)) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Room Exists No Need To Create It 1"+RoomTitle);
                    RoomName(RoomTitle,false);

                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(otherUserRoom)){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Room Exists No Need To Create It 2 "+otherUserRoom);

                    RoomName(otherUserRoom,false);

                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"None Of the above Room exist so Create one with RoomTitle "+RoomName);
                    RoomName(RoomTitle,true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.getDetails());
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled Calling "+databaseError.toString());

            }


        });
```

This method i created to call `FireBaseDatabase.updateChildren(RoomName)` which is not calling from If Else Statement of my previous code.

```
public void RoomName (String Name,boolean RoomExist){

    if (RoomExist){
        Log.d(TAG,"Room Not Exist Creating One in METHOD NAME ROOM NAME "+RoomExist);
        RoomName.put(Name, "");
        FireBaseDatabase.updateChildren(RoomName);
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"Method ROOM NAME CALLING Value Of ROOM NAME FINAL "+Name);
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat_Screen.class);
    intent.putExtra("Get_Phone", UserData.getPhone());
    intent.putExtra("Get_Image", UserData.getImage());
    intent.putExtra("Get_Name", UserData.getName());
    intent.putExtra("Get_Other",Name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now my `onDataChange` call as i want.I hope it will someone who has same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forget to indicate the name of your database reference in the function `getReference()`.

For example, if you want to get the messages objects you need to set the DatabaseReference with something like

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
```

And the url of my database looks like :

https://myproject.firebaseio.com/message

This url is indicate on the top of the RealTimeDatabase tab in your Firebase dashboard.

Hope this help.

Comment: i am adding child at root when onDatachanged called so before this there is no child i am referring to root. `FirebaseDatabaseFirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` return to root and i am adding room into root

Comment: Check Image above to get idea how my nodes looks in FirebaseDatabase

Comment: Try this DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

Comment: Thx for ur response cedic i did almost all type of method of database in getting reference like `gerParent` , `getRoot` etc

Comment: I am still working on it i hope i will resolve it soon and i will come with solution